# Handling directed margin and padding when changing the direction

Tags: html, css

When changing the html dir attribute from ltr to rtl, all directed margins and paddings need to be reversed :

```
[dir='ltr'] {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

[dir='rtl'] {
  margin-right: 80px;
}
```

Is there another better approach?

Comment: I don't think there is a *magic* way to do this, it depends on the site you are developping and the CSS you are writing. You simply need to consider this and do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you need to reverse every instance of e.g. margin and you are using some css preprocessor such as sass. You could create the following mixin:

```
@mixin horizontal-margin($left: initial, $right: initial) {
  &[dir="ltr"] {
    margin-left: $left;
    margin-right: $right
  }

  &[dir="rtl"] {
    margin-right: $right;
    margin-right: $left;
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

`p {
  background: blue;
  @include horizontal-margin(16px, 48px);
}`

and in your html
`<p dir="ltr"> some text</p>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: in this case. We need dir with every tag. Can we do it only with body tag?